# Unable to return list in linq query when using different tables with inner joins

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote linq query which joins 3 tables. I want to return data in the form of list. But as per my knowledge list will not carry data that belongs to other table. 
This is my query.

```
public List<ts_upld_doc> GetDetails(int client_id, int emp_id, int empcitizen_id)
{
   var truecondn = 
    (from c in db.ts_upld_doc 
     where (((c.upld_clientid == client_id && c.upld_employeeid == emp_id 
              && empcitizen_id == 0) 
           || (c.upld_clientid == client_id && c.upld_empcitizenid == empcitizen_id 
              && emp_id == 0)) 
           || (client_id == 0 && emp_id == 0 && c.upld_empcitizenid == empcitizen_id)) 
           && c.upld_doc_delstatus == 0 select c).ToList();

   if(truecondn.Count>0)
   {
      var data = 
       (from up in db.ts_upld_doc 
        join doc in db.tm_doc_type on up.upld_docid equals doc.doc_typeid 
        join content in db.tr_upld_content on up.upld_docid equals content.upld_docid 
        where content.upld_contentlabel == "Expiry Date" 
        select new 
        {
           doc.doctype_name, 
           doc.doc_typeid, 
           content.upld_contentvalue 
        }).ToList();                  
   }
   return truecondn;             
}
```

List will carry data belongs to this table. But my query var data contains data from multiple tables. So what is the best way to carry data to controller. I have written this query in DAL. which return type i should use here? I want the data in the form of List form because in controller i am binding this data to model. But it may not be possible. Do i need to create viewmodel that can carry data of multiple tables in the form of List<>. Please suggest.

This is my viewmodel and pococlasses

```
 public class MyViewModel
    {

        public ts_upld_doc upload_document { get; set; }
        public IList<ts_upld_doc> Upload_List { get; set; }


    }
    public class PocoClasses
    {
        public virtual int upld_docid { get; set; }
        public virtual string upld_contentlabel { get; set; }
        public virtual string upld_contentvalue { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my query.

```
public List<PocoClasses> GetDetails(int client_id, int emp_id, int empcitizen_id)
        {

                var result = (from up in db.ts_upld_doc
                              join doc in db.tm_doc_type on up.upld_docid equals doc.doc_typeid
                              join content in db.tr_upld_content on up.upld_docid equals content.upld_docid
                              select new PocoClasses
                                  {
                                      upld_docid = content.upld_docid,
                                      upld_contentlabel=content.upld_contentlabel,
                                      upld_contentvalue=content.upld_contentvalue


                                  });

            return result.ToList();
        }
        This is how i am trying to bind data to model.


List<PocoClasses> ts = docdel.GetDetails(client_id, emp_id, empcitizen_id);
  model.Upload_List = ts;
```

Comment: Use [data transfer objects](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create some DTO / POCO classes to "transport" your data from the data access layer through to your business layer and on.

So define a plain old class object MyDto with simple property get;set fields.
Put those classes somewhere you can share them with your Dal and Business layer code.

```
public List<MyDto> GetDetails(....
{
    var result = (from c in ctx.Table1
                  join p in ctx.Table2 on c.ClientId equals p.ClientId
                  select new MyDto
                  {
                     ClientId = c.ClientId,
                     Field2 = p.SomeField 
                  }

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Okay. So inside MyDto class i should declare fields or other classes?

Comment: Sir Can you give me small example to create poco classes? Confused about what to declare inside poco classes?

Comment: I tried above but i am not able to bind list to model. I tried something like this. I will post the code above.

Comment: I figured out. Thank you richardb